# Android Program (Adding items to ListView in another activity)

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I am curious how I would go about adding an an editText variable to a list in another activity. I have created an arrayList that names are stored into as they are entered in the editText line. These are stored in the nameList variable in the class StartingActivity. How would i go about adding and showing these names into a ListView in another activity and class called ListActivity as shown. Thank you. Also, how do i refractor the names of classes and files without it just basically not making my program runable.

Code:

```
 Class StartingActivity:
 public void onClick_btnConfirm {
 EditText editName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editName);
 TextView textOutput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textOutput);
 Intent intentList = new Intent(StartingActivity.this, ListActivity.class);

 if(editName.length()!=0) {
        nameList.add(editName.getText().toString());
        editName.setText("");
    }

    //intentList.putExtra("Name", editName.toString());

    startActivity(intentList);
}





Class ListActivity:
public class ListActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listAthletes);
    final StartingActivity nameList = new StartingActivity();
    nameList.getNameList();
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, nameList.getNameList());
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run findviewbyid() for an id in another Activity.[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23554885/2670775) answer might be of help to you. If that is not what you really want to go with, you can do two things:

1. Send Intents with the string.
2. Use a sharedPreference and write the string to a sharedPreference. SharedPreferences also have an OnChangeListener, so you will be able know if the preference has changed. In the onResume() of that activity , you can just read from the sharedPreference, and update the UI
3. Also take a look at AsyncTask [here](http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2013/01/why-and-how-to-use-asynctask.html#.U7jLXJSSy08)
4. As mentioned , you can also use the SQLite Database

Comment: 4. Store the text in a SQLite database